# How to perform calculations with floats in python?

Tags: python, math, floating-point

How can I properly calculate with floats in Python? Whenever I calculate normally, the numbers are so inaccurate. I expected more from a numeric-oriented language like Python.

Python Version: 3.7

Code:

```
4.2+8.9
```

Result:

```
13.100000000000001
```

This might not seem like much, but since I am writing an algorithm that adds numbers to floating point numbers hundreds of times, this starts to become an issue.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you mean by 'inaccurate', together with the code and python version you used to obtain the inaccurate results?

Comment: @Relaxisys--Python provides several options for increased precision over normal floating-point.  One option is using the [Decimal module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html).  In this case Decimal('4.2')+Decimal('8.9') equals 13.1

Comment: Are you dealing with something discrete, like money amounts, or with the results of physical measurements?